# Is it possible to make the desktop background transparent or otherwise hidden?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I'm running Ubuntu in a virtual machine via VirtualBox. I have the seamless mode turned on, which is pretty cool. However, if I move an Ubuntu window around quickly, I can see the redraw of the ubuntu background quickly before it's hidden by VirtualBox again. This isn't a huge deal, but I'd like to fix it, if possible.

I see two possible options that don't involve changing VirtualBox code:

1. Make the Ubuntu desktop transparent
2. Make the Ubuntu desktop hidden entirely

Is it possible to do either?

I know that Compiz Fusion has/had a feature to do this for their cube effects, but I don't think that I can run this on the VM. And, even if I could, I don't want to run those services for this one small feature.

My host OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same wallpaper in the VM and in the Host?

Comment: I'm doing that now, but it still draws a flicker behind the Ubuntu window.

Comment: I think its just something that happens when you run a VM. If you were to make the background transparent, it would possibly show up as black.

Comment: I thought that might help. I asked in the original question if anyone knew how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What you could also do is to run gconf-editor, to go to /apps/nautilus/preferences and to uncheck the show desktop entry, then, your wallpaper should disappear.
P.S. note that you will loose right click on the desktop and desktop icons.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off having Gnome to draw the background. Install `gconf-editor` if you do not have it, run `gconf-editor`, go to `/desktop/gnome/background` and uncheck the `draw_background` value. Not only does it fix the problem, it also is much more responsive.